# Open WPF form Outlook Vsto with parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, vsto

I have an Outlook vsto which adds a `Button` to the preview pane of the selected mail.
For now the vsto only has the purpose of adding the button, but additional functionality is to come.

Additional I have a WPF `Window` which opens when the `Button` is clicked.

```
 private void ArchiveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var mail = (Outlook.MailItem)OutlookItem; // currently selected mail.
     var app = new App();
     app.InitializeComponent();
     app.Run(new MainWindow(mail));
 }
```

As you can see I can run the App.xaml to get the stylings and pass the parameter `mail` to the window.
In this `MainWindow` I edit some metadata and initiate the storing process, so I need that Outlook.MailItem object.

The solution I found was to have two constructors of MainWindow. One called by `app.InitializeComponent()` which seems to load the styling and is immediately closed and one called by `app.Run(new MainWindow(mail))` which I actually use.

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
     Close();
 }

 public MainWindow(Outlook.MailItem mail)
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     SearchTextBox.Text = mail == null ? "null" : "mail"; // checking if the WPF got the object
     MailItem = mail;
     ...
 }
```

My question here is:

Is there a cleaner/ better solution to get both, styling and the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are manually creating the WPF main window from code, remove the `StartupUri` definition from `App.xaml` file.

If it is defined, it will be automatically created by WPF infrastructure, hence the window blinking.

Comment: Works exactly how I wanted it to. Thank you very much.